# Create a mutiple workbooks based on unique values in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create multiple workbooks based on unique values in column. My code creates the first workbook with name of unique value(Col C) ,based on unique values in column 'c'  but later its not working.

```
ColA        colB          Colc(uniques values)
1.John      ram           micheal
2.Andrea    Boll          Holger
3.schmidt   Muller        Arnold
4.ram       loki          rainer
5.puv      ramesh        shanu
6.jogesh   naga          chiru
```

Code:

```
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim x As String
 Dim LastRow as integer

LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 2 To LastRow     
     x = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("C" & i).Value

    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    With NewBook
        .Title = x

        .SaveAs Filename:=x & ".xlsx"
    End With
    Next
```

result:

```
Micheal.xlsx
Holger.xlsx
Arnold.xlsx
rainer.xlsx
shanu.xlsx
chiru.xlsx
```

I got only micheal.xlsx workbook. can someone please look at my code and correct me.

Comment: `LastRow` is not declared in the sub. So, VBA will automatically assume it to be 0. That means `For i = 2 to 0`. You might want to include a line like `LastRow = 6`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:
1. You didn't declare `LastRow` in your code.
2. You need to change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`. Because when you create a new workbook the new workbook becomes the active workbook and the code won't work anymore. With `ThisWorkbook` this error won't happen.

```
Public Sub CreateSomeWorkbooks()

Dim i As Integer
Dim x As String
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("C" & i).Value
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    With NewBook
        .Title = x
        .SaveAs Filename:=x & ".xlsx"
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry I forget to put the 'LastRow' sytax in my code. Now i have added in my code. even though i got an errors. could you please look at again to my code.

Comment: Use my code instead. Your code is missing `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)` before the row `LastRow = ...` and `End With` after that row. Your code with these changes or my code.... it's your choice.